# polymer breaks document.evaluate (xpath)

Tags: javascript, polymer, document.evaluate

I'm using Chrome 34.0.1847.116 on Linux and if simply just load polymer.js, then document.evaluate no longer works, and returns strange error:

"Error: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The context node provided is null.
    at Error (native)

Here's an example

http://jsbin.com/jadir/2/edit?html,console,output

I'll create an issue unless I hear otherwise, but posting here in case someone has some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you filed a bug against the [ShadowDOM Polyfill](https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues).

Fwiw, you can make your example work by *unwrapping* the div before sending to evaluate, like this:

`document.evaluate('span', unwrap(div));`

... but this is a workaround and will cause other problems. For example, any nodes you extract from the result will need to be *wrapped* before using in most cases (`wrap(node)`).

Comment: Thanks for doing that.